# How to access main class function from material UI button component?

Tags: javascript

I want to call function `handleKeyPress()` from ToDo.js file in AddButton.js file to set action `onClick()` for a button from Material UI. May be I should set onClick action for button in some different way ? But any types of import/export declarations dos not work for me.
I want to understand some functions access rules, I'm newbie in JS )
Please tell me what is wrong here.

**AddButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import AddIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Add';
import {handleKey} from '../ToDo';

const styles = theme => ({
  button: {
    margin: theme.spacing.unit,
  },
});

function FloatingActionButtons(props) {
  const { classes } = props;
  return (
    <div>
      <Button variant="fab" color="primary" aria-label="Add" className={classes.button} onClick={() => (handleKey)}>
        <AddIcon />
      </Button>
    </div>
  );
}

FloatingActionButtons.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FloatingActionButtons);
```

**ToDo.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import './ToDo.css';
import ToDoItem from './components/ToDoItem';
import AppBar from './components/AppBar';
import AddButton from './components/AddButton';
import Logo from './assets/logo.png';

const appBar = <AppBar />
const addButton = <AddButton />

class ToDo extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [
                {
                    title: 'Cup cleaning',
                    todo: "Wash and take away the Kurzhiy's cup from WC"
                },
                {
                    title: 'Smoking rollton',
                    todo: 'Do some rollton and cigarettes'
                },
                {
                    title: 'Curious dream',
                    todo: 'Build a time machine'
                }
            ],
            title: '',
            todo: ''
        };
    };

    createNewToDoItem = () => {
      this.setState(({ list, title, todo }) => ({
        list: [
            ...list,
          {
            title,  
            todo
          }
        ],
        title: '',
        todo: ''
      }));
    };

    handleKeyPress = e => {
        if (e.target.value !== '') {
          if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            this.createNewToDoItem();
          }

        }
    };

    handleTitleInput = e => {
      this.setState({
        title: e.target.value,
      });
    };

    handleTodoInput = e => {
        this.setState({
         todo: e.target.value
      });
    };

    deleteItem = indexToDelete => {
        this.setState(({ list }) => ({
          list: list.filter((toDo, index) => index !== indexToDelete)
      }));
    };

    editItem = (i, updTitle, updToDo) => {
        let arr = this.state.list;
        arr[i].title = updTitle;
        arr[i].todo = updToDo;
        this.setState ({list: arr});
    };

    eachToDo = (item, i) => {
        return <ToDoItem
                    key={i}
                    title={item.title}
                    todo={item.todo}
                    deleteItem={this.deleteItem.bind(this, i)}
                    editItem={this.editItem.bind(this, i)}
                />
      };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="ToDo">
                <img className="Logo" src={Logo} alt="React logo"/>
                <h1 className="ToDo-Header">{appBar}</h1>
                <div className="ToDo-Container">

                    <div className="ToDo-Content">
                        {this.state.list.map(this.eachToDo)}
                    </div>

                    <div>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new title" value={this.state.title} onChange={this.handleTitleInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <input type="text" placeholder="Enter new todo" value={this.state.todo} onChange={this.handleTodoInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress}/>
                       <button className="ToDo-Add" onClick={this.createNewToDoItem}>+</button>
                       <p>{addButton}</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default ToDo;
export const handleKey = this.handleKeyPress;
console.log(handleKey)
```

Comment: You should show any errors you get. Also, you can debug/inspect your code via any browser developer mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You refer with this to a property or a method not to a variable, so you shouldn't be using this here at all. 
Secondly you will have to import handleKeyPress method to your file first to be able to access it, are you sure that the method is in `const { classes } = props;` here ? and if yes you should then point the onclick={handleKeyPress()} just to one function it is not necessary to create an arrow function which returns a function { classes } and not to the props, then it should be working

Comment: Marek, so I tried like this: export {handleKeyPress}; and import { handleKeyPress } from '../ToDo'; and got ./src/ToDo.js
  Line 116:  'handleKeyPress' is not defined  no-undef. What is wrong ?

Comment: Also tried export const handleKey = this.handleKeyPress; and import {handleKey} from '../ToDo';, but this time there is no response from key press.